# How to create a timeline control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create (or download, but I can't find any) a timeline control. What I have in mind is something like this:

[image: screenshot]

In this image I am only interested in the timetable, with the resource on the left and the time horizontal.

Does anyone can tell me what a good way is to develop such control? I have tried the tablelayout control, but I am stuck now, because I can't plan something that takes 2 minutes. I also don't want to draw a column for every minute because of the performance and it looks too busy.

Comment: Are you looking for a meeting room booking system ?

Comment: I can show the way for creating this but for download, I never saw anything like this before for free.

Comment: Look here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/TimeLine.aspx, can be useful

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: No I am not, I've used this picture only to illustrate what I want.

Comment: @MahanGM If you can help me to create such a control, I would appreciate that

Comment: @Tigran Thanks, but I just want to diplay a static view

Comment: I wanted to write it in a source now but it would take time. My recommend is to not work with windows controls and draw all of these stuffs by the power of GDI+. Create a user control and perform all of paint actions in the way you want, actually it's not easy as I introduced like this but it just need time to create. I'll post an answer with source if no one posts anything useful till that time.

Comment: @Martin: wouldn't be it easier to do something in `Excel`? Some macro with grafic and you pass parameters from outside...

Comment: @MahanGM Thank you, I really appreciate it. Is the GDI+ the way other vendors are doing it to(Telerik, devexpress, devcomponents)? I don't have any experience with GDI+ but I don't mind to learn it.

Comment: The `Graphics` object which is in the `Paint` event also is the managed form of GDI+. I don't know how these companies are getting through with UIs but I know that lots of user interfaces are designed with the hand drawn codes! I mean not the windows or mac ui.

Comment: @OrhanCinar This is a asp.net control. I am looking for a winforms control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telerik and DevExpress are great about these kinds of stuffs but since they're not free, using them should be hard for us poor people :).

I can call this project as a prototype because it needs a lot of work to get fitted in the place that you want.
http://www.4shared.com/zip/cGKq8yLt/Timeline.html

Any question will be getting answered if I would be on the Stack.

**EDIT**

For scrolling it's better to not use a scroll control because it would make the work harder. Add two buttons, one for moving to 1 hour ago and the other one for moving to next 1 hour. You can change the factor 1 for moving in large steps. Then in the `Paint` event at the part of `Draw items` you should calculate what's the view port of current visible times. It might be a little hard.

**UPDATE**

I've seen people coming here more than what I was expecting and since I've removed previous source from here, today I wrote a much better timeline control to put for download for others. You can get it from the above link which I've renewed it. The good thing about this new version is that you can give times like this: 9:15 or 10:48. But, since the grid is snapped in hours and half hours, it'll go outside of lines.

This is an image from source:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! That is exaclty what I need. You've done this very quick! It would take me a whole day to come up with somehing like this! The only thing I am trying to add is the possibility to plan appointments (reservation) on the minute. It must be possible to create an appointment that takes 2 minutes.

Comment: Your welcome! For making it able to get minutes some little changes are needed. I hope you do it yourself. It's simple.

Comment: Yes I want to try it myself. I was thinking to use the start and end time as seconds. One more question, how can I display a scrollbar when the form isn't maximized?

Comment: I wanted to tell about scrolling at first but you know I just wasn't in the mood. I'll put it in the answer.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot. I'm at work now, so I can't work further on it, but I will let you know how things are going. I will try to build in the possibility to plan in minutes...

Comment: File link in original post is no longer valid. Does anyone have a copy of the file?

Comment: The question itself is old and I've deleted the file from my 4shared account and my PC since 1 or 2 months ago. Would be glad to help you but can't.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't completely integrated it into a Winforms app yet, but I found the open source [Sony ATF Timeline control](https://github.com/SonyWWS/ATF/wiki/ATF-Timeline-Editor-Sample).

[image: Sony AFT Timeline control]

It uses the MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) to assemble the components, so I'm not sure how easy it will be to drop into a standard Winforms application.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik stuff is normally pretty good looking, its not free though (but a lot cheaper than doing it yourself), take a look here http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/scheduler.aspx

devexpress also has one http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Scheduler/ and it has a free trial option too

Comment: Thanks, but the only thing I want is what the picture is showing: a resource on the left, the time horizontal and appointments in the 'table'.